# Nginx caching redirect responses (302) for images

Tags: caching, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've defined the below nginx cache to config.

```
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {

        proxy_cache folder;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;

        proxy_cache_valid any 0;

        proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$host$request_uri;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        proxy_pass http://upstream_folder;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_send_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $x_forwareded_for;

        keepalive_timeout 5;
    }
```

I don't want to cache the non 200 requests static content like img/css/js/gif etc.

But for the requests like the below which has a 302 redirect response, nginx caches it. Please let me know what is wrong with my ningx config. And how to avoid the 302 response caching for images or any static content.

```
    curl 'https://localhost:9000/hello.jpg' --verbose
    *   Trying localhost....
    * Connected to localhost (ip) port 443 (#0)
    * TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    > GET /support.jpg HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost
    > User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
    > Accept: */*
    > 
    < HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
    < Server: nginx/1.8.0
    < Date: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 00:47:51 GMT
    < Content-Type: image/jpeg
    < Content-Length: 0
    < Connection: keep-alive
    < Cache-Control: public, max-age=315358505
    < Expires: Fri, 17 Dec 2027 00:22:56 GMT
    < Location: https://localhost:9000/login.jspa?referer=%252Fhello.jpg&hint=
    < P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
    < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    < X-JVL: D=16190 t=1513642992041808
    < X-Robots-Tag: none
```